# elapsed time with unsigned tickCount / Wrapping

Tags: c++

i have a own GetTickCount() function returning an unsigned int (the count rolls over to zero on 0xFFFFFFFF)

i cant measure an elapsed time with:

```
unsigned int elapsed;
unsigned int start = GetTickCount();
LongOperation();
unsigned int stop = GetTickCount();

if (stop >= start )
   elapsed = stop - start;
else
   elapsed = (INT_MAX - start) + stop;
```

is this the same if i do a cast to signed (the time span i measure is always less than what can be represented in a signed integer - i think about 24 days) ? :

```
int start = (int)GetTickCount();
LongOperation();
int elapsedTime = (int)GetTickCount() - start;
```

if i look at the .net Environmet.TickCount property:

> *TickCount will increment from zero to Int32..::.MaxValue for approximately 24.9 days, then jump to Int32..::.MinValue, which is a negative number, then increment back to zero during the next 24.9 days.*

so when i cast my GetTickCount() function to a signed integer i should get the behaviour from .net (wrapping occurs on 0x7FFFFFFF->0x80000000) ?

with this should be possible do measure the elapsed time as follow (seen in another post):

```
int start = Environment.TickCount; 
DoLongRunningOperation(); 
int elapsedTime = Environment.TickCount - start;
```

Comment: No. Time elapsed may fit in an integer, but typecasting to signed integer for 'start' and 'end' could given wrong values.

Answer (score 3):

The prototype for `GetTickCount()` in C++ in Windows is:

```cpp
DWORD WINAPI GetTickCount(void);
```

So, I would code it like this (similar to the other answers):

```cpp
DWORD start = GetTickCount();
dosomething();
DWORD elapsed = GetTickCount() - start;
```

Will measure elapsed times up to the maximum number `DWORD` can represent.

As others have said, with unsigned arithmetic, you don't need to worry about the counter wrapping around - try it yourself...

Also check `GetTickCount64()` and `QueryPerformanceCounter()`/`QueryPerformanceFrequency()`.  `GetTickCount64()` will allow you to measure longer intervals, but it is not supported on all versions of Windows, while `QueryPerformanceCounter()` allows you to measure to much higher resolution and accuracy.  For example, on some Windows versions, `GetTickCount()` may only be accurate to about 18ms while `QueryPerformanceCounter()` will be better than 1us.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure GetTickCount() is the preferred function to your problem.

Can't you just use QueryPerformanceFrequency()? There's a nice example at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In C++, if you stick with unsigned, the code will work:

```
unsigned int start = gettickcount();
DoLongRunningOperation();
unsigned int elapsedTime = static_cast<unsigned int>(gettickcount()) - start;
```

The reason you want to stick with unsigned is that unsigned arithmetic is required to use modulo arithmetic which is what you want in this case.