# Thread-safe GetTickCount64 implementation for Windows XP

Tags: winapi

I'm targeting Windows XP, and I need a function similar to GetTickCount64, that does not overflow.

I couldn't find a decent solution that is correct and thread safe, so I tried to roll my own.

Here's what I came up with:

```
ULONGLONG MyGetTickCount64(void)
{
    static volatile DWORD dwHigh = 0;
    static volatile DWORD dwLastLow = 0;
    DWORD dwTickCount;

    dwTickCount = GetTickCount();
    if(dwTickCount < (DWORD)InterlockedExchange(&dwLastLow, dwTickCount))
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&dwHigh);
    }

    return (ULONGLONG)dwTickCount | (ULONGLONG)dwHigh << 32;
}
```

Is it really thread safe?

Thread safety is difficult to check for correctness, so I'm not sure whether it's really correct in all cases.

Comment: No, that's not thread-safe.

Comment: It's not even correct. Your call to `InterlockedIncrement` is a guess at best. You also appear to be using `volatile` to mean something else than it does: [volatile vs. volatile](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I guess I have yet to learn a thing or two about lock-free programming. Well, I tried :)

In fact, I solved my issue in another way... By doing nothing :) It appears that when calculating the difference between two GetTickCount results, 49-days overflowing doesn't really screw up the results (unless the time difference is that large). http://stackoverflow.com/a/3692425/2604492

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows the timer overflow problem in usually solved (in games) with using `QueryPerformanceCounter()` functions instead of `GetTickCount()`:

```
double GetCycles() const
{
    LARGE_INTEGER T1;
    QueryPerformanceCounter( &T1 );
    return static_cast<double>( T1.QuadPart );
}
```

Then you can multiply this number by reciprocal number of cycles per second to convert cycles to seconds:

```
void Initialize()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER Freq;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency( &Freq );
    double CyclesPerSecond = static_cast<double>( Freq.QuadPart );
    RecipCyclesPerSecond = 1.0 / CyclesPerSecond;
}
```

After initialization, this code is thread safe:

```
double GetSeconds() const
{
    return GetCycles() * RecipCyclesPerSecond;
}
```

You can also checkout the full source code (portable between Windows and many other platforms) from our open-source Linderdaum Engine: http://www.linderdaum.com

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It perfectly answers my question, so I'm marking it as accepted, although I found another solution: as I only calculate time differences, it turns out that 49-day overflowing is not an issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3692425/2604492

Comment: The resolution of ``QueryPerformanceCounter()`` is much higher compared to ``GetTickCount()``, up to nanoseconds.